# Oauth2 security configuration antmatchers request filtering not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on a simple spring boot project along with spring security oauth2 to use google authentication for a specified endpoint which is `/google/login`.

With following security configurations everything is  working perfectly.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfigure extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ldap/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

But I need to specify only `/google/login` endpoint to authenticate with oauth2. Therefore I specified it like this.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfigure extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/google/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ldap/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

with this security configuration `http://localhost:8080/google/login` endpoint call redirects to another endpoint called `http://localhost:8081/oauth2/authorization/google` which is I haven't defined.

[image]

Please help me to overcome this problem. Thank you.

Comment: This looks expected. As soon as spring-security-oauth2 is configured, it will automatically create couple of endpoints like one for sending authorization request, one is to consume oauth code.

Comment: As soon as login request comes, it will redirect to authorization endpoint which is generally /oauth2/authorization/{client}. In your case, it is /oauth2/authorization/google assuming google is configured as client in your application configuration. Similarly there will be one endpoint like /oauth2/code/{client} which is to consume auth code. Please read the documentation before using this.

Comment: @Akash if that so can you please suggest a way to do this. I only need authenticate this "google/login" endpoint with oauth2

Comment: Assuming you have only one Security configuration in your application, you can try http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/google/login/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll().and().oauth2Login(); It will allow all the request without authentication except /google/login which will redirect to configured google login.

Answer (score 1):

This configuration works for me. I had to allow all endpoints that were redirecting while Google's authentication process was running.

```
@Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/google/**","/oauth2/authorization/google","/login/oauth2/code/google")
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ldap/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2Login();
        }
```